# Translating a domain name into a IP Address

Tags: dns, cmd.exe, ip, ipv4

Suppose we have a website with a domain name of "www.youtube.com".Is it possible for us humans to translate this directly into a IP Address(IPv4)  just by looking at which is after the last dot?Or do we have to run `tracert` on a command line terminal to find the IP Address?I have found a term called "URL to IP Address lookup" but Wikipedia doesnt have a page assosciated with it and other websites dont explain it very well.

Comment: No and no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain

Answer (score 2):

No - you can't translate a domain name to an IP address just by looking at the last ".".    You also don't need to run tracert.   This system does not work quite how I expect you think it does.

To convert a domain name to an IP address you use DNS. DNS is a simple database service which advised the information associated with a domain name.

The simple (and very incomplete) answer to your question - To find the IP address associated with a domain name you need to query a DNS server.  Your computers operating system has a mechanism (called a DNS resolver) built into it do to do this.   There are a few ways you can ask it for the information you want.

Arguably easiest would be to using "ping" - eg "ping www.youtube.com" - This will do an IP address lookup, show it on the screen and see if that host is reachable using ping.  More correctly though most OS's have a program called "[nslookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup)".  You can normally do something like

```
 nslookup www.youtube.com
```

And it will call your OS's mechanisms to look up the IP address.

**More Advanced Stuff**

A domain can have multiple resources associated with it - not only an IP address.  These records commonly include an MX record to help with delivery of mail, TXT records with other generic information helpful to the Internet and other resources as well.    They can also include CNAME records which - loosely speaking - reference a domain to another domain, which can then be looked up to get its IP address.   There are other, more advanced records as well.

DNS is a hierarchy with caching and the ability to provide different answers to different systems.   It is one of the earlier systems the Internet relies on.  There is a lot more to debugging DNS then doing simple queries - some of which can be done with nslookup - although there are other tools which are arguably better. https://activedirectorypro.com/use-nslookup-check-dns-records/ has some examples of more advanced usage of nslookup under Windows.

Comment: Domains can have *multiple* IP addresses - `nslookup www.youtube.com` is a good example that show exactly that.

Comment: @DavidPostill absolutely.   They can also have IPV4 and IPV6 addresses